# Can't find my user directories in jira 7.9.2..directories is missing

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

Can't find my user directories in jira 7.9.2..directories is missing

yesterday Jira directory is there but the now I can't find user directorie[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNUw0.png)

Need to resolve it and solution
please fix it...I can't see the user directories..
is there any plugin is there.
Need to resolve it and solution
please fix it...I can't see the user directories..
is there any plugin is there.Need to resolve it and solution
please fix it...I can't see the user directories..
is there any plugin is there.Need to resolve it and solution
please fix it...I can't see the user directories..
is there any plugin is there.Need to resolve it and solution
please fix it...I can't see the user directories..
is there any plugin is there.